# Control of large number of analog devices

Tags: fpga, adc, dac, photonics

For research that I work on we have photonic chips that have 100-200 analog devices on board. I wish to control these devices at a rate of ~-1 MHz from an fpga.

Some require a current source and others a voltage source. As a solution to this I was wondering using the LVDS pins on an FPGA and PWMing the signal. If it’s attached to a current source we can directly drive it. If it’s attached to a voltage source we can drive a capacitor with the lvds signal.

I was wondering what people thought about this approach.

Comment: Not enough info

Answer (score 3):

a 1MHz current source is not the kind of thing you can easily DIY, instead you would probably be looking at a current output DAC, even then setting time and non linearity will take some careful planing to ensure you can reach that.

For the LVDS, it will come down to what kind of voltage range you need, and what response time you need, to get n bits of PWM resolution generally takes a modulation frequency at least 2^n higher,

You also have not given an idea on budget, as a 1.7 MSPS 8 bit voltage DAC in 100 units quantity is about $1.60 each from a quick search, so you could always throw hardware at the problem for not to high a cost.